# How to display an additional attribute of the gallery blueimp-gallery?

Tags: javascript

On the default documentation like this

```html
    <a href="https://farm2.static.flickr.com/1922/43884115510_310bfa1548_b.jpg"
 title="Land of a Thousand Summits" data-gallery="">
<img src="https://farm2.static.flickr.com/1922/43884115510_310bfa1548_s.jpg"></a>
```

I want to add an attribute **author**, and then display it. And this is where I am having the issue, I have no idea how to display the author name.

```html
<a href="https://farm2.static.flickr.com/1922/43884115510_310bfa1548_b.jpg"
 title="Land of a Thousand Summits" data-gallery=""
author="Pavel" 
>
<img src="https://farm2.static.flickr.com/1922/43884115510_310bfa1548_s.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: You question is unclear, where do you want to display it?

Comment: next to the name

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to Add attribute in a tag....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<a href="...">link</a>

<p>Click the button to create an attribute with the value "test" and insert it to the "a" element.

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    var att = document.createAttribute("author");
    att.value = "nameAuthor";
    a.setAttributeNode(att);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to display additional attributes, not just the title

Comment: how do you want get the name author?

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for isn't possible, mainly because when you click on the link, the site is actually redirected to the file's page. So what you are seeing in snippet view isn't your page that had the link.

This means that you can't just attach the image and display the author, because you have no control on the image display page. Flickr (in this case) has control over how that page is displayed.

What you can do is use a library like [Lightbox.js](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). This library allows you to have images that are thumbnails and when clicked they show the who image and you can add addition info (e.g. author name)